# Keychain Access not revealing passwords

Tags: macos, keychain, bug

I was able to fix the problem by restarting my computer, but I wanted to see if anyone else had this issue.

If I right click on a keychain item and select "Copy Password to Clipboard" the usual password confirmation dialog box didn't come up and the password isn't copied.

If I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and check the "Show Password" box, the confirmation dialog box does not show up and the check disappears after a fraction of a second.

I also tried locking the login keychain thinking that maybe if I locked and unlocked it the behavior would be fixed. But clicking the lock in the top left corner does nothing.

Like I said, restarting fixed the issue.

---

**Edit:**

So this is happening again about a month later.

I opened console and there is nothing logged under "All Messages" when I click the "Show Password:" checkbox.

When trying to copy an application password rather than a web form I get: "Access to this item is restricted (-25320)"

Keychain first aid says there is nothing wrong with the keychain.

Comment: Does the problem recur?

Comment: Not since restarting.

Comment: Well, I'm going to restart again because I need to use my computer. Maybe next time it happens someone will be able to help.

Comment: I have a similar situation, but I made one observation: Passwords that I set several months ago are working properly. Passwords that I set only recently will not show. For web passwords it is possible to reveal them in Safari, but with mail passwords it appears to be impossible.

Comment: Have kind of a similar situation, a bit more details — http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/keychain-wont-let-copy-passwords-after-10-11-1-update