# Keychain won't let copy passwords after 10.11.1 update

Tags: security, software-update, macos, keychain, bug

After the 10.11.1 update, I can not get access to some of encrypted data stored in my keychains with *Keychain Access.app*. Most notably, I can not see or copy passwords stored.

Normally, to do so, you'd have to:

1. unlock a keychain with keychain password;
2. unlock an item itself with keychain password.

During 2nd step, when password is typed in, you can select 2 options: "Allow" and "Always allow". The difference is that if you click "Always allow", you won't have to perform 2nd step for this item again.

Here's some things I was able to detect:

- if I had clicked "Always allow" on an item before OS X update, I can access it fully;
- if I haven't clicked "Always allow", I can not copy password from right click menu, nor see it when ticking "Show Password" checkbox on Info Screen.
- if I add new item, I can not copy password from right click menu, but can still see it on Info Screen.

I get what seems to be mostly full keychain data using following command (though, I am not sure everything's there):

```
security dump-keychain -d elmigranto.keychain
```

---

**UPD:** After more detective work, I found following message appearing in *Console.app* when I click anything in password dialog:

```
26.10.15 10:19:52,345 SecurityAgent[770]: Ignoring user action since the dialog has received events from an untrusted source
```

---

**UPD2:** Pretty sure this is caused by [HT205375](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205375), which among other changes lists the following:

> **SecurityAgent**
>
> Available for: OS X El Capitan 10.11
>
> Impact: A malicious application can programmatically control keychain access prompts
>
> Description: A method existed for applications to create synthetic clicks on keychain prompts. This was addressed by disabling synthetic clicks for keychain access windows.
>
> CVE-ID
>
> CVE-2015-5943

Comment: Do you have any third-party utilities running, like Alfred, KeyCue, TextExpander, etc?

Comment: @Kent Nice tip, looks like MagicPrefs causes this behaviour.

Comment: Great!  That's what I expected.  I expanded on what is (probably) happening a little in the answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but maybe related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214834/keychain-wont-reveal-forgotten-password-how-to-fix

Comment: Works fine now on 10.11.5, at least for installing signing certificates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Third-party utilities such as Alfred, TextExpander, or MagicPrefs might appear to take "control" of the window as far as the OS is concerned.  You can find the culprit by disabling them all, and turning them on one by one until you find one (or more) which affects Keychain in that manner.

You can add the offending program to the list of approved apps ( System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Accessibility ) and this issue will go away.  *(hat tip to @elmigranto for this addenda)*

Comment: The solution to this is to add a program to the list under System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Accessibility — then you won't have to quit an app every time Keychain prompt pops up.

Comment: Glad that there's a setting to change.  I haven't upgraded anything to ElCap yet, so was not sure where to go about adding the trusted apps.

Comment: @elmigranto any way to determine what app cause such a malfunction of the keychain prompt? Is it triggers when suspicious app is running, or when found them on a disk? I've tried to add as much apps as I suspected in a using of global hooks [Flycut, Karabiner, MagicPrefs, PuntoSwitcher, Seil], but got no success.

Comment: @std.denis I am not really sure, when I quit MagicPrefs, problem disappeared, but I imagine some apps may have daemons running in the background or something similar. Try quitting those apps and killing every process related to them, see if that helps. Maybe diff list of processes in safe boot and normal boot.

Comment: @elmigranto it's kinda magical – after my comment I've gave up with no luck in fix of this issue, and put macbook into a sleep. In the morning, when I turned it on and tried once again – problem is disappeared =)

Comment: For me it was caused by SmoothMouse.  I can't seem to add it to the list of approved apps since it's enabled through the System Preferences.

Comment: If you cannot add the preference itself ( it should be in /Library/PreferencePanes/ or ~/Library/PreferencePanes/ ) then, you might try to add the actual binary, which would be in the Contents/MacOS/ folder of the above.

Comment: worked partially for me; it pointed me to the cause (Magic Prefs), but the only way I found is to quit Magic Prefs, click "Always" (or Allow) and then relaunch it. Not ideal but acceptable

Comment: For me, deleting MagicPrefs resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - VMware Fusion was the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem trying to edit the keychain while screen sharing. Even when I had direct access to the server, if the other computer was still screen sharing, it would fail in this way. After stopping the screen sharing and making the changes directly on the server, it worked.

Comment: Even after we disconnected from Screen Sharing it still didn't work, we had to reboot the box and drive it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this same issue if you are using Synergy screen sharing.  Re-adding synergyd to the accessibility pane or re-installing will not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

MagicPref causes the issue in my case. The problem disappeared once I uninstall MagicPref.

Comment: a less drastic option is to simply quit it, do what you must and then relaunch it

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here just in case. I did not have any kind of mouse-preferences software. But after carefully closing and opening many applications after a reboot, I found the culprit:

I was running Mumble (voip software)

After closing Mumble and reopening Xcode, everything went back to normal.

Edit: Wondering why I got a downvote. Mumble software uses screen overlay and virtual keyboard technologies, which macOS identifies as a potential security threat. Your down vote won't change that.